# How to customize the Excel Function Wizard?

Tags: excel, winapi, xll

I would like to customize the Excel Function Wizard, for instance by adding some buttons to the window and/or by firing a new event when the user press the OK Button.

I know that It is possible because the Bloomberg Excel Add-in implemented it.

I found no information about it on the web. I guess that I have to intercept calls to the Windows API and to play with the handle of this window to achieve this but I'm not sure. I see no way to do it via the Excel COM API or the Excel C API but I may be wrong.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

ps: I'm taking about the following window :

[image: Excel Function Wizard]

---

**EDIT**

See below a screenshot of the Bloomberg Wizard with a hyperlink for the optional argument that open a new window (not natively supported by the Excel C API)

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of Bloomberg Addin?

Comment: @SMeaden done, sorry for the delay. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47038906/3205529

Comment: Try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687900.aspx and at `pxArgumentHelp1`

Comment: @SMeaden This does not help as `pxArgumentHelp` does not accept hyperlinks.

Comment: Using this (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MoveWindow.html) you can resize and move the modal function wizard window if you want.