# How to add options hyperlink into Excel Function Arguments Window just like bloomberg's BDH function?

Tags: excel, vsto, xll, vba

I have developed a excel UDF.
One of the UDF parameters has known possible values (A, B, C).
So instead of asking all my users to find out what the possible values are I want to provide a option1 (hyperlink) in excel function wizard just like the [Bloomberg's BDH function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP8f0.png) as shown in the screenshot.

I know I have to somehow hook upto win32 api and override the call/window when the function wizard is invoked. 
When I look into SPY++ I see that there is a [insert function window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0vo1.png) and [function arguments window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x45L0.png).

I have broken down the task at hand into 4 sub tasks:

1. Subclass the window “Function Arguments” bosa_sdm_XL9
2. Add hyperlink control to that subclassed window.
3. Hook an event to open another control with available options for
   that parameter.
4. Hook an event to populate the value back in subclassed window when
   the control is closed.

I think I can sub class a window using online documentation but need help with **item# 2,3,4**.

Could not find any good code samples or starters on stackoverflow/msdn.
Has anyone accomplished this or a similar task?
Please help.

Comment: Can you not use a custom form for this?

Comment: No. I will loose most of the excel wizard functionality including range selection from excel to set parameter values.

Comment: I'm investigating this, could you confirm that the SPY++  screen capture are made on the Bloomberg-modified Excel function wizard ? (and not on a normal Function Wizard). Ps : I have asked a similar question  ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/43351767/3205529 )

Comment: @Malick - Will get back to you on this.

Comment: @Malick - So I installed the 64 bit addin from https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/software-updates/. I don't have the license but I installed it and opened up BDH function's function arguments dialog. SPY++ still shows up bosa_sdm_XL9. Check it out and let me know if you make any progress.